# Which Backend technology would be best for my React-Admin App? (Simple online Database)

Tags: backend, react-admin

I want to create a simple Web-Database but am unsure which technology to use.

**My goal:**
Create a simple Web Application which I, as well as two of my partners can use to track addresses and projects. (So about 6 DB tables + some support tables for those)
Have an authentication system, where people need to log-in in order to get access.
It would also be cool, if I can write my own additions, for example to attaches files to an entry, but not upload it to the DB but via FTP.
I would also love to have rights management, like giving certain users access to only certain addresses.

Restrictions:
Due to my hosting plan, I can only use JS and PHP (And obviously HTML, CSS), so no Python or similar.

**My current plan:**
I think it's pretty obvious to go with React-Admin for the Front-End.
For the backend, I am really unsure.
I found this tutorial how to make a PHP API including JWT: [Here](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2018/09/rest-api-authentication-example-php-jwt-tutorial.html)
And actually was able to make a simple, test API: (Empty Get request to https://timto.site/api.php)

But it would require me to manually do a lot of things, which I'd like to avoid.
So I found systems like CouchDB which seems to handle for example the rights management, but I don't really see through what is good to use/fulfills my need and which don't.

**Question**:
Does any of you, have recommendations for which Technology I should use (Specifically backend) it would be very cool to have a functioning example, which I can use to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use PHP, and not only is restricted to it, take a look at:

https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/

and

https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/

Uses PHP, and based on PHP classes, automatically setup an API and a "meta" API of the API itself, which then is consumed on the front-end by the admin (react-admin under the hood) to automatically generates lists and forms, field, etc. The admin is fully customizable, e.g., you can have some automatic resources and other hand-made resources.

But, you can also use Google Firestore and Google's Firebase Auth, with no backend at all. There are two data and auth providers adapters available:

https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase

https://github.com/rafalzawadzki/ra-data-firestore-client

You access firestore direct from react-admin, and every call is authenticated and custom authorized directly with firebase auth.
You dont need to setup any server, nor provision any resource.
A possible drawnback is, with firestore being a NoSQL database, you can't do SQL queries on it.